# Add a resource (image) to an executable file

Tags: c#

I have a Windows console application that should generate HTML output. In that HTML output, a certain JPEG image should be processed and the result included as base64 inline-image in HTML.

Right now, I have the JPEG on the disk and load it for processing:

```
Image image = Image.FromFile("test.jpeg");
```

but I am asked to remove the dependency on the disk by somehow adding the image into the EXE. How would I do that; does C# support embedded image resources?

Comment: Why don't you just include them in the solution and copy them to the output directory?

Comment: Yes, you can right click on project in VS -> properties -> resources -> add resource

Comment: 1) Create resourse file in project explorer. 2) Click on it 3) Click add file 4) Add your jpeg 5) Access it like so - `var content = MyNamespace.Properties.Resources.MyJpeg;`

Comment: @Alexander targeting *which* framework? Full Framework or .NET Core? In the Full Framework the resource designer generates strongly typed properties, just as it does for `Settings`.

Comment: @Polly That was what I was searching for; however, I was searching at Right click on Project -> Add -> ...